# grab bg-color of a div and apply to another using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, background-color

How do i dynamically grab the bgcolor of a div with certain ID and apply that bgcolor to previous div? Is it possible using jquery?
I wanna grab the bgcolor of the #s4-ribbonrow and apply that background to the previous DIV "maincontainer" using jquery...can someone give me some idea..

[image]

Comment: This is certainly possible using jQuery. It would help to show your HTML.

Comment: Is `maincontainer` the ID of the div?

Comment: please see the image link..i couldn't attacht an image here..

Comment: While I edited your question to include the image, please post the (relevant) HTML (not a *picture* of the HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward:

```
$('.maincontainer').css('background-color',$('#s4-ribbonrow').css('background-color'));
```

All we are doing here is specifying the background-color of .maincontainer with css(), using the value for background-color that if finds in #s4-ribbonrow